# gem install nmatrix - You need a version of g++ which supports -std=c++0x or -std=c++11

Tags: c++, ruby, gcc, rubygems

I'm installing `nmatrix` on Mac OS X (10.11.3 (15D21)) using `gem install nmatrix` and getting this error message:

```
checking for apparent GNU g++ binary with C++0x/C++11 support...
  ⏎ Exception `RuntimeError' at extconf.rb:141 - You need a version
  ⏎ of g++ which supports -std=c++0x or -std=c++11. 
  ⏎ If you're on a Mac and using Homebrew, we recommend
  ⏎ using mac-brew-gcc.sh to install a more recent g++.
```

The `nmatrix` page mentions `gcc` but not `g++` - i.e. https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix/wiki/Installation

Any suggestions?

Comment: And your target OS is ....... ?

Comment: Did you try `mac-brew-gcc.sh` as _clearly specified in the error message_?

Answer (score -2):

g++ is a compiler executable file of GCC

you shoud add flags to compile settings:

```
-std=c++0x
```

or

```
-std=c++11
```

Comment: I'm installing a Ruby gem like this: gem install nmatrix. Not sure how I'd add those flags.